# Debian won't change the ip setting

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ip

When I go to Network setting and change the settings from DCHP to manual and set the IP then press save. The settings doesn't change. If I type

```
sudo ifconfig
```

I still see the old Ip and gateway that PC got from DCHP
If I use

```
dhclient -r eth0
```

I still got the old IP that i get from DCHP, not the one that I set manually.

Comment: Have you checked if your router (dhcp server) uses mac-address reservation and if your clients IP is mapped to the mac-address. Try to remove the lease on the router and try again.

Comment: @ValentinB I don't have any issues when I use router with DCHP. But  when I use a new brand router by default it have DCHP off and I should a IP and change the gateway. So I set IPv4 to manual and add 192.168.1.** and gateway 192.168.1.1 then press SAVE. But when I type ifconfig I still have the old IP that I get by DCHP and it doesn't change to the manual one that I just set

Comment: Where you add the IP and gateway? In NetworkManager? After saving changes try to restart NetworkManager service. Probably "Save" button don't do it :) Other way: you can add the needed IP temporary via terminal using `sudo ip a a...` The full content of this command you find in `man ip`.

Comment: you need to use `ip` and not `ifconfig`. Secondly. Try `ip link set eth0 down` and `ip link set eth0 up`. Optionally  `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`

Comment: @ValentinB `ifconfig` is fine and will show him the ip address. You are correct in that he either needs to use `ifdown etho`, `ifup eth0`.

Comment: @NasirRiley `ifconfig` is everything except fine. From the man page `NOTE
       This program is obsolete!  For replacement check ip addr and ip link.  For statistics use ip -s link.`

Comment: @ValentinB It is not obsolete. It just isn't there by default with some distros including Debian but you can still install it. It's there by default with RHEL, SUSE Enterprise Linux, and CentOS which are all widely used. Do you think that enterprise-level OS's like RHEL and SEL would have it there by default if it were obsolete? Does it not give the needed needed information when used? Many users and admins still use it so that flies in the face of there being something wrong with it.

Comment: @NasirRiley I think we are going beyond the OP's question. One thing for example `ifconfig` doesn't do is list additional IP addresses (aliases) configured for an interface. It is not included in CentOS7 on minimal install and should be avoided in general.

Comment: @ValentinB That doesn't apply in this case. He is just looking for an ip address and not aliases. It is included in in both RHEL and SEL which are enterprise-level, is widely used by both regular users and admins, and gives what is necessary most of the time which is just to see the ip address, gateway, and subnet mask, end of story. It is not beyond the OP's question as you brought it up and suggested that there was something wrong with it for his purposes. Like it or not, your statement that it should be avoided and your suggestion that it's terrible is undeniably and demonstrably wrong.

Comment: Lots of argument over a command that is just being used to see network status.  No requests for clarification on important things like the version of Debian, and thus the applicability and mechanism of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the configuration file :

```
nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/connection_name
```

Modify this section (this is an example of a static IP):

```
[ipv4]
address1=192.168.100.121/24,192.168.100.1
dns=8.8.8.8;
dns-search=
method=manual
```

Replace the `method=auto` with `method=manual`

And the `address1=192.168.100.121/24,192.168.100.1` with the preferred IP address and your gatway:

```
address1=IP_address/24,gatway
```

Then restart the NetworkManager:

```
systemctl restart network-manager
```